# How to position elements under each other automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The elements have to be under each other because in my script on some action a element will be moved from the bottom of the page to the top. When this happens on for example the 3rd image, the 3rd image will slide to the top but its old position is now a white gap.

Sometimes I don't get it whether I have to use absolute, relative, fixed, static and so on.

HTML:

```
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <img id='img1' src='./images/image1.jpg' alt='img1'>
            <br />
            <img id='img2' src='./images/image2.jpg' alt='img2'>
            <br />
            <img id='img3' src='./images/image3.jpg' alt='img3'>
            <br />
            <img id='img4' src='./images/image4.jpg' alt='img4'>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
            body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #wrapper{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #img1{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top:0px;
            }
            #img2{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100%
            }
            #img3{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 200%;
            }
            #img4{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 300%;
            }
```

And my JavaScript for letting a element disappear on a certain action.

```
else {

        curr++;

        $('#img'+curr).animate({
            top: '0px'
        }, 1200);



        setTimeout(
             function() {
                $('#img'+(curr-1)).css('display', 'none');
              }, 1200);

      }
```

Comment: Since you posted 90% of your code you could have added a fiddle along with it.

Comment: Please add a working example in http://jsfiddle.net or similar.

Comment: Sorry i didnt think about that. But here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/6bxoxs66/

Comment: A tip unrelated to your question: Do not repeat the same CSS over and over again. Instead, create a class containing the five lines all the images have in common, and style the class instead of every single image.

Comment: Also, since `body` and `#wrapper` have the same styles, you can just do `body, #wrapper { ... }` to avoid repeating the same thing twice.

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6bxoxs66/3/

Comment: For your animating actions you could use css transform with translateY and transition for smoothness - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_translatey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <img id='img1' src='./images/image1.jpg' alt='img1'>

        <img id='img2' src='./images/image2.jpg' alt='img2'>

        <img id='img3' src='./images/image3.jpg' alt='img3'>

        <img id='img4' src='./images/image4.jpg' alt='img4'>
    </div>

        #wrapper{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #wrapper img {
            display: block;
        }
```

`display: block;` on `<img>` element; Now your img element will behave like a block element, no need to position it absolute or use `<br/>`, all images will go one after the other

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to your positions and the top atributes then just switch to relative, otherwise go with the *display:block;*
I suggest also to read this:

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

example:

```
   body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #wrapper{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #img1{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                top:0px;
            }
            #img2{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
               position: relative;
                top: 100%
            }
            #img3{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                 position: relative;
                top: 200%;
            }
            #img4{
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                top: 300%;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
 display:block;
```

for this, also you can give

```
 witdh:100%;
```

and set

```
 margion:0 auto;
```

also try below:

```
 http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
```